# Alterar margin padrão de 8px do body no Angular 2

Tags: angular

Boa tarde, estou iniciando com Angular 2 e estou tendo um problema para retirar a margens do body de 8px, já tentei incluir na tag body do css margin:0, porem não deu em nada.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Aqui está a tag body que está no meu app component css

```css
body,html {  
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat Light";
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

E aqui o app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: Os códigos que você postou não estão funcionando, você poderia revisar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após instalar o normalize.css digitando:

```
npm install normalize.css
```

Não se esqueça de referenciar o arquivo no seu projeto. No caso de um projeto angular você pode incluir a referência no arquivo styles.css, dependendo da localização seria algo do tipo:

```
@import 'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resetar os estilos de cada browser, é considerado uma boa prática usar o nomalize.css, https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css .
Uma outra abordagem seria adicionar `!important` a propriedade desejada, mas isso é considerada uma má pratica para o CSS.

Comment: Concordo com @matheuscla, é preferível usar uma folha de css para normalizar os seus estilos do que a regra **!important**. Aliás eu desaconselho o seu uso, especialmente no desenvolvimento de algo feito do zero.

Comment: @mateus Adiciono diretamente no index.hmtl ou faço por npm?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei instalando o Bootstrap através do Angular/cli, segui o seguinte tutorial: [Link da configuração](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md)

Depois adicionei o Bootstrap no index.html:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Funcionou perfeitamente bem! ;)